# Why is the Sterling currency symbol encoded by the MVC HtmlEncode?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-encode

MVC.net will accept most currency symbols, allowing them through the html encode process untouched. But the UK Sterling symbol £ is replaced with the html code 
:

```
&#163;
```

If you post

```
₠ ₡ ₢ ₣ ₤ ₥ ₦ ₧ ₨ ₩ ₪ ₫ € ₭ ₮ ₯ ₰ ₱ ₲ ₳ ₴ ₵ ₶ ₷ ₸ ₹ ₺ ₻ ₼ ₽ ₾ ₿ $ £
```

it encodes to:

```
₠ ₡ ₢ ₣ ₤ ₥ ₦ ₧ ₨ ₩ ₪ ₫ € ₭ ₮ ₯ ₰ ₱ ₲ ₳ ₴ ₵ ₶ ₷ ₸ ₹ ₺ ₻ ₼ ₽ ₾ ₿ $ &#163;
```

What is special about the £ symbol that requires it to be encoded when none of the others are? What security risk does this character present?

Comment: use HTTPUtility.URLEncode. share the code

Comment: Sounds like this problem related to page encoding (ISO-8859-1 or Latin-1 used to save the view). Try re-saving the view page in UTF-8 and add meta tag like `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`, and see if the request returns proper sign.

Comment: the page is UTF-8, but I think this is unrelated to the page rendering. The encoding happes server side. You can reproduce just by calling string s = HttpServerUtility.HtmlEncode("£$");